# Internet singificantly slower when using wifi

Tags: networking, wireless

Download speed using ethernet: 70 Mbps
Download speed using wifi: 2 Mbps

I have connectivity issues when using wifi sometimes as well, even though signal is fine. On W7, wifi works just fine.

```
    description: Ethernet interface
       product: NetLink BCM57781 Gigabit Ethernet PCIe
       vendor: Broadcom Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:07:00.0
       logical name: eth0
       version: 10
       serial: b8:70:f4:4b:67:e1
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi msix pciexpress bus_master cap_list rom ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=tg3 driverversion=3.134 firmware=sb latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair
       resources: irq:16 memory:f1800000-f180ffff memory:f1810000-f181ffff memory:f1820000-f18207ff
  *-network
       description: Wireless interface
       product: Centrino Wireless-N 1000 [Condor Peak]
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:08:00.0
       logical name: wlan0
       version: 00
       serial: 74:e5:0b:46:46:08
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=3.13.0-46-generic firmware=39.31.5.1 build 35138 ip=192.168.0.108 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11bgn
       resources: irq:51 memory:f1b00000-f1b01fff
```

I have tried some quick fixes and driver reinstalls with no luck so far. Problem is, I cant actually figure out whats causing the problem so I have no idea where to look for solution.

Comment: Please note that depending on the signal, protocol, band, .... The wireless bandwith can be A LOT smaller than wired.

Comment: i was sitting right next to the router when doing the speed comparison

Comment: So, a few things to consider:
1. It doesn't matter how good the signal is if the protocol doesn't support higher speeds.
2. The signal can still be bad, even if you're next to the router. A lot of household items like a microwave emit interfering energy at the same bandwidth.
3. The router of the neigbour can also be interfering.

It's best to do the same test on Windows, and do it as fast as possible on Ubuntu so you are sure the problem is Ubuntu.

If that is the case, I'd suggest you submit a bugreport to the kernel. This seems to be a bug.

Comment: I have stated in the post that wifi on Windows 7 works fine. The wifi also works ok for everyone esle in the apartament (windows users) the wifi also works definitely better on all other devices - phones, tablets etc. My phone tends to notify FB posts, emails etc literally seconds faster than my laptop. Even if I have those websites open.
I will try to reinstall the whole system and if it wont work, I will fill up the bug report. Thanks for assistance.

Comment: I'm talking about the speed you measured, not the connectivity issues you have. I'd also like to add that 2 Mbps is really fast. This should not be a problem at all. So again, to clarify what I'm trying to say: **the measured difference in speed is probably normal. Even at 2Mbps, you should not notice any of the problems you describe. This sounds like a kernel bug, you can report it in launchpad, they will gladly help you further**

Comment: I have had the exact same problem for months. Windows, Android, Ios all tests wifi internet speeds in the 50:s-70:s Mbps where my Ubuntu 15.10 laptop only reaches about 2.5 standing right next to the router. Wired it's reaching >100. I installed a new router a few days ago and the problem persists.

How did you go about to solve the problem?

Answer (score 1):

About the only couple things you can do is have the wifi access point set to WPA2 with no WEP or TKIP, check the results from `iwlist scan` for your connection.  And with the intel card `gksudo /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf` and see if there is a line `options iwlwifi 11n_disable=8` if a line exists that shows `11n_disabled=1` change it to 8, save, exit and reboot